# Declaring space characters in PATH for MSYS2 - Windows

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, msys2, msys

I used this command to declare PATH to MSYS2.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/bin
```

This worked however, i want to add another path. I know that `:` is the path separator.

The new directory is located at `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin`.

Given the previous path, i know that this path should be converted to something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/bin:/c/Program Files/CMake/bin
```

My question is, how do i declare the SPACE character? (The one in 'Program Files')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Use this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/bin:/c/Program\ Files/CMake/bin
```

The character `\` is the one that cancels the space character.

Answer (score 3):

Just add "" to specify the string.

export PATH=$PATH:/c/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/bin:"/c/Program Files/CMake/bin"

Comment: It's ok, you just have to make sure that you take care of the space characters. Look to my answer above.